# 'this' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I am newbie in C ,with Mingw32 compiler.
Right now i am creating decompiler from IL to C (Native)

The code generated (Without System.Object):

**DecompileTestApplication_Program.c**

```
#include "DecompileTestApplication_Program.h"
DecompileTestApplication_Program* DecompileTestApplication_Program__ctor( ) {
    if (array__DecompileTestApplication_Program == 0) {
        array__DecompileTestApplication_Program=(void**)malloc(sizeof(void*)*(capacity__DecompileTestApplication_Program=4));
    }
    DecompileTestApplication_Program* this;
    //error: 'this' undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (count__DecompileTestApplication_Program==0) {
        this=(DecompileTestApplication_Program*)malloc(sizeof(DecompileTestApplication_Program));
        goto RealConstructor;
    }
    this=(DecompileTestApplication_Program*)array__DecompileTestApplication_Program[--count__DecompileTestApplication_Program];
    RealConstructor:
    this->ind = 0;
    this->a = 1;
    this->b = 3;
    //this._inherit_object_( ); //this is OOP tests ,still working on it
    return this;
}
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Main( ) {
    int var_0_02;
    var_0_02 = 0;
    var_0_02 = ( var_0_02 + 1 );
    int var_1_08;
    var_1_08 = 1;
    int var_2_0A;
    var_2_0A = 3;
    var_1_08 = ( var_1_08 + var_2_0A );
    var_0_02 = ( var_0_02 + ( var_1_08 + var_2_0A ) );
    DecompileTestApplication_Program_blat = ( DecompileTestApplication_Program_blat + ++DecompileTestApplication_Program_bpa );
}
void DecompileTestApplication_Program__cctor( ) {
    DecompileTestApplication_Program_blat = 1;
    DecompileTestApplication_Program_bpa = 4;
}
```

**DecompileTestApplication_Program.h**

```
#ifndef DecompileTestApplication_Program
#define DecompileTestApplication_Program
/*
Type's Name: DecompileTestApplication.Program
Time to Parse: 40.0023ms
*/
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    //Variables
    int ind;
    int a;
    int b;
} DecompileTestApplication_Program;
static int DecompileTestApplication_Program_blat;
static int DecompileTestApplication_Program_bpa;
//Methods
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Main( );
DecompileTestApplication_Program* DecompileTestApplication_Program__ctor( );
void DecompileTestApplication_Program__cctor( );
static int count__DecompileTestApplication_Program=0;
static int capacity__DecompileTestApplication_Program=0;
static DecompileTestApplication_Program** array__DecompileTestApplication_Program=0;
#endif
```

**@main.h**

```
void main();
```

**@main.cpp**

```
//bookmart for includes
#include "DecompileTestApplication_Program.h"


void main() {
    //bookmark for initialize
    DecompileTestApplication_Program__cctor();
    DecompileTestApplication_Program_Main();
}
```

The error found in the first file.
I searched the resolve for this error for awhile ,
but didn't found any.

Comment: Are you sure you decompiled a plain C file? Rather seems like C++.

Comment: It's generated from IL to make OOP ,i am still working on it. H2CO3 ,how i can make it like C?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what the problem is, but that's mainly because there's rather a lot of code here.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) by stripping out everything you know to be irrelevant.

Comment: What compiler are you using to compile the generated C source? Maybe it can't handle declarations between statements, or it keeps `this` as a reserved word for C++ compatibility?

Comment: For some reason it didn't recognize `DecompileTestApplication_Program* this;` as a declaration.

Comment: one thing for sure, auto generated stuffs sucks. Look at the generated code, its barely readable. Same goes for generated assembler. Only generated stuffs which i find useful the stuffs generated by flex.

Comment: Thanks Oil Charleswoth ,i'll read that. Joachim Pileborg ,Dev-Cpp to compile with original C. (Without `this` keyword) Aftnix ,It's generated from IL ,there alot of names in IL that deletes after compiling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define DecompileTestApplication_Program
```

That means that everywhere you see the word `DecompileTestApplication_Program`, it gets removed. As such, your attempted declaration of `this`:

```
DecompileTestApplication_Program* this;
```

expands to

```
* this;
```

which attempts to dereference the undeclared variable `this`. To fix this, change the macro name.

Comment: Good catch.  Normal practice is to make the macro name have a leading and/or trailing `_` character (or two).  Kinda dumb of an autogenerator to make that mistake.

Comment: Personally, I use `H_HEADERNAME`. Try to avoid leading `_` characters, in most cases it's not valid (reserved namespace), but trailing `_` characters would work just fine.

Comment: Hot Licks ,this generator developed alright one day. (I am the developer) It's ok for him to make that mistake.

Comment: @SuperFile -- OK -- I was under the impression you were using someone else's pre-existing generator.

Comment: (And actually C's whole include scheme was mucked up from the start -- the ifdef/define at the start of every include shouldn't even be necessary.  Older languages managed to do includes just fine without the need for such nonsense.)

Comment: Yeah i hate that too ,but this lang is faster than C++ (with the correct usage) ,than i wanna use it for making easy lang but for programming games.